# Load CSV file into MariaDB that automatically creates table through python

Tags: docker, csv, mariadb, docker-container

I have some csv files which i want to upload on database in mariadb docker container that automatically creates table out of the csv file through python with headers of csv file as column names of table.

Comment: A table in database is not created using csv files. You need to create a table using a sql query. Then write your python script for entering data using those csvs into the database table.

Comment: i did it by using sqlalchemy and by df.to_sql() of pandas and it worked!!!